# Inclusion Exclusion Principle Problem

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

> There are 28 people in your family consisting of 18 adults, 13 females, and 11 who have purple hair.  There are 11 adult females, 6 of whom sport purple hair.  There are 10 adults with purple hair.  No female children have purple hair.  How many male children without purple hair are in the family?

I know this problem is an application of the inclusion exclusion principle. However I am not sure how to express one of the statements in the prompt:  "No female children have purple hair. How many male children without purple hair are in the family?"

I'm pretty confident in expressing the rest up until that sentence:

A = adults, F = females, P = purple hair, and $N()$ represents the cardinal number of a set

$N(A) = 18$

$N(F) = 13$

$N(P) = 11$

$N(A \cap F) = 11$

$N(A \cap F \cap P) = 6$

$N(A \cap P) = 10$

I thought maybe it meant $N(F \cap P)=0$, but when I did that I didn't get the right answer which is 7.

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi @BrianM.Scott.  Thanks for your response.  Even for a 3 set I'm still not sure how to express the last statement:  "No female children have purple hair."  Is it $N(F \cup P \cup A')=0$?

Comment: $A\cup F$ denotes people that are either adult or female.  $A\cap F$ denotes people that are both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No female children have purple hair.

If $X$ is the set of female children with purple hair, we’re told that $N(X)=0$. The problem, then, is to express $X$ in terms of $F$, $A$, and $P$. If you’re made a Venn diagram, you can see that $X$ is the region inside both $F$ and $P$, but outside $A$. In other words, $X=(F\cap P)\setminus A$. If you’re more accustomed to complements than to set differences, you might be more familiar with that as $X=F\cap P\cap A^c$.

Comment: Thanks @BrianM.Scott.  So I see they are asking for $N(F' \cap A' \cap P')$.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: @user1527227: Yes, that’s exactly right. You’re welcome!

Comment: In the inclusion exclusion principle it states $N(a \cup b \cup c) = N(a) + N(b) + N(c) - N(a \cap b) - N(a \cap c) - N(b \cap c) + N(a \cap b \cap c).$  But here they give you a piece that is not direct in this equation, so I solved it by drawing a venn diagram.  Is that how you would do it or would you try an manipulate equation some how?

Comment: @user1527227: For a problem of this size I’d simply use a Venn diagram, just as you did.